# No wifi using Ubuntu on laptops

Tags: wireless

I have loaded Ubuntu onto two different laptops and both had the same result...no WiFi. I could access the internet if I plugged into Ethernet port but try as I might, I just could not access WiFi. I even tried Wine to install a Windows based external usb WiFi device but again...nothing. It functioned normally in Windows but with Ubuntu installed....nothing and this was the same whether it installed just Ubuntu or dual booted with Windows. Any suggestions? Thx!

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the wifi driver. Go to `additional drivers` to download and apply a driver on your system. If you can't find additional drivers then go to `software sources/softwares and updates`, *go to the last tab Additional Drivers*. From there you can enable your Wifi driver.